# Resizable navigation bar and buttons 'a la' Forbes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the navigation bar on the Forbes website:
[link here](http://www.forbes.com/)

The buttons in the navigation bar resize themselves to always cover 100% of the window width.

The way I've tried this is by setting a min and max width for my header tag and a min and max width for each button on my bar:

```
header {
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}

header #Title {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

header #ButtonA {
    min-width: 120px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

header #ButtonB {
    min-width: 120px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The header is resizing fine between the min and max widths. However the width of my buttons is not changing at all. They are fixed width no matter how large my current window is.

Comment: @AlienArrays Thanks but gave that a try. It sets my buttons to their max-width, ie 200px. They still don't resize when I shrink the window.

Answer (score 1):

By setting min- and max-widths, you are only setting limits to what widths the buttons can't exceed. Try making the button elements block-level ("display: block;") so that they naturally would span 100% of their parent container, but don't because of your min- and max-width limits.

Alternatively (and my preferred option), instead of setting min- and max-widths, set the width of each element to be percentages. For example (change the widths for your design):

```
header #Title {
    width: 40%;
}

header #ButtonA,
header #ButtonB {
    width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Percentage widths are based on the width of the parent container. In this case, you want the buttons to be a percentage of your full width header, so the solution is to set your buttons' width percentage as a percentage of the full width. For example, if you have 5 buttons, then the width of each would be 20% (1/5th of 100%).

Here is a CodePen with an example of this: http://www.codepen.io/kyleatfine/pen/okxcz

You might also consider using a Flexbox layout to accomplish this as well. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/